# CSS Trouble with Pinned Header Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header div on my page that when the page is scrolled down to the header area, it is pinned at the top (via position:'fixed', and top:0), but the problem is that the content div that sits below it ends up shifting up after the position attribute is changed, filling the space that the header div used to take up. Does anyone know how to fix it so that the content below the header doesn't slide up once the position is changed to fixed?

Thanks in advance!! Below is the code that I am using, which uses JQuery to pin the header:

```
    <html>

    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        .para {

           background-color:yellow;

        }

        .pinned {
            background-color:#0000FF;
        }

        #pinHeader.fixed {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          width:100%;
        }

    </style>

    </head>


    <body>

    <div>

                         <div>
                              <h1>Nav goes here</h1>

                         </div>


                            <div>

                                        <div id="pinHeader" class="pinned">

                                                <h1> Main Header </h1>
                                                <h2>Sub header goes here</h2>
                                                <hr />

                                        </div>

                            </div> 


                                    <!-- main content goes here -->

            <div id="mainContent">

                                                  <h2>Content 1</h2>
                                                  <p class="para">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah<br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                  </p> 

                                                  <h2>Content 2</h2>
                                                  <p class="para">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah<br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                  </p> 

                                                  <h2>Content 3</h2>
                                                  <p class="para">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah<br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                  </p> 

                                                  <h2>Content 4</h2>
                                                  <p class="para">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah<br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                     blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah <br />
                                                  </p>                                   

            </div>


    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    var divTop = null;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            pinnedPanel();

        });

        jQuery(window).resize(function() {

            pinnedPanel();

        });

        divTop = jQuery('#pinHeader').offset().top;
    });

    var pinned = false;

    function pinnedPanel() {

    var stickHeader = jQuery('#pinHeader');

    var contentDiv = jQuery('#mainContent');

      // what the y position of the scroll is
      var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

      if (y >= divTop) {
            stickHeader.addClass('fixed');
            pinned = true;

      } else if (pinned) {
            stickHeader.removeClass('fixed');
            pinned = false;

      }

    }

    </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add height of stickHeader to margin-top of contentDiv, and revert it back to whatever it was before (assuming zero here) on unpin.

```
if (y >= divTop) {
    stickHeader.addClass('fixed');
    contentDiv.css('margin-top', stickHeader.height())
    pinned = true;

} else if (pinned) {
    stickHeader.removeClass('fixed');
    contentDiv.css('margin-top', 0)
    pinned = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using margin-top for the header div... [try it..](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya/R25ZC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the nav-bar whether to the top or bottom results in layering you otherwise avoid.  SO: if you figure out the amount of space the bar takes up, specifically the height.. and the you either add or subtract that difference from the margin-top.

If you want the content not to bump up towards the top the header:

```
margin-top: -some px;
```

If you want the content to move down the page:

```
margin-top: some px;
```