# Is there a simple jQuery function to pin and unpin an h1 tag?

Tags: jquery, q

I'm aware of [scrollerama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) and [superscrollerama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/).

I've struggled with them both for a couple days. And I can't get them to function for just the pinning. I don't need the animations and type support. I try using the sample doc and stripping out HTML content one block element at a time and the page breaks. Seems scrollerama only works when the entire example is present. Or more likely.... I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

All I want to do is pin an `<h1></h1>` tag and then unpin it when a specific tag is reached.

I've also seen this question here: [CSS Trouble with Pinned Header Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274020/css-trouble-with-pinned-header-div) but that doesn't seem to function at all.

Example code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<article>
    <header></header>
    <section id="wrap">

        <h1> Pin this when it hits the window top</h1>
        <div class="innercontent">
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p class="unpin">Unpin the previous h1 tag when this hits window top</p>
        </div>

        <h1> Pin this when it hits the window top</h1>
        <div class="innercontent">
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p class="unpin">Unpin the previous h1 tag when this hits window top</p>
        </div>

        <h1>Pin this when it hits the window top</h1>
        <div class="innercontent">
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p>inner content here</p>
        <p class="unpin">Unpin the previous h1 tag when this hits window top</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

A link to some jquery function example somewhere would be exceptionally helpful. Or a quick explanation of how to strip scrollerama down to only the pin/upin function would help.

### Additional:

sbeliv01 suggested this question: [How to find the closest element to the current position with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760567/how-to-find-the-closest-element-to-the-current-position-with-jquery)

However that method fails when margins have been adjusted (reset for HTML5). It only works if there's absolutely no margin adjustment on an element. And when attempting to simply wrap H1 tags in an unstyled div, there's a terrible flicker upon page scrolling.

This is non-functional, but I've set up a 
jsFiddle to play with as needed: 
[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/ffdFd/2/)
As you can see things pin just fine, but then they fail to unpin.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760567/how-to-find-the-closest-element-to-the-current-position-with-jquery

Comment: Based on that question.... Issue becomes that any removeClass jquery fails if there's a margin applied to the element and wrapping the element in a div with no styling, causes a horrible flicker upon scrolling.

Comment: Have you posted this on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @radarbob No. This isn't really an "app" question. it's merely a jquery question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with it a bit and using Phillip Wills' suggestions, I've gotten code settled to where it seems to be functioning dramatically better.

There was no issue with the if/else statement I was using before. Seems the issue was merely with what position to use in the jquery.

functional jquery:

```
  $(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        $('.info').each(function() {
          var pin = $(this);
          var inner = pin.next().position().top - $(window).scrollTop();
          var ptop = pin.height() + 20;

            if (inner < ptop) {
                pin.addClass('pinned');
            } else {
                pin.removeClass('pinned');
            }
        });        
    });
});
```

The main issue was finding the top of the next object, which Phillip helped with and then finding the top of the pinned object with a bit of additional room for the scrolling.

<kbd>[**Functional jsFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/ffdFd/8/)</kbd>

Comment: yeah the if/else switch was fine. The issue was the target of the scroll. While your answer assisted greatly in targeting that, it still wasn't quite correct in addition to requiring manual alteration for any additional use due to all the hard coded numbers. This new structure is much more fluid and can easily be repeated without alteration.

Comment: But the unpinning does'nt work, as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzrXa/2/). See also my solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tzrXa/3/)

Comment: @Enzino that's cloning, not pinning. And unpinning works in my fiddle above. Grants, it unpins at the next pin element, but it still unpins. I realize the pins stack essentially, but due to the nature of pinning, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tweak the values some, but making a second if statement, instead of using else, seems to do the trick... This is some updated code inside your anonymous function:

```
var bottom = pin.next().position().top + pin.next().height() - $(window).scrollTop();
var inner = pin.next().position().top - $(window).scrollTop();
console.log(position, bottom, inner);

if (position <= 0 && bottom >= 50 && inner <= 15) {
   pin.addClass('pin');
} 
if (bottom <= 30 || inner >= 15) {
   pin.removeClass('pin');
}
```

Here's a link to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ffdFd/3/

Comment: Thanks, your fiddle link seems to be broken. But with some adjustments, I've got it much smoother and working: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/ffdFd/5/ I appreciate the extra eyes. Thanks again. There's a delay in the bounty award.